# How do I tell if data formatting inconsistencies are themselves consistent?

Tags: sql, database

A client has sent us a couple of tables that we need to be able to cross reference against each other. Unfortunately, the columns that we need to use for cross-referencing have inconsistently formatted data.

However, it *looks like* they are inconsistent in a consistent way. I.e., in one column, there is a "name", and in the other column there is a name preceded by a 4 digit id code and a space, so "1234 name".

If it's true that the inconsistencies are consistent, then we can use the data as is just by calling the MySQL substring function. But I'm not convinced. How do I know for certain whether the inconsistencies are universal? What if there are other inconsistencies that I'm not seeing?

What I need to know is, do all the unique values in columnA = all the unique values in substring(columnB, 6).

I'm not great at MySQL and have tried a few queries, but they've either returned *all* results (not distinct ones) or they've gotten "interrupted" on the server since there's a lot of data and they take forever to run. Help?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about analyst work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `not exists` clause:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t2.name = substring(t1.columnB, 6)
                 );
```

This will identify all `t1.columnB` that do not have a matching name in `t2` by the rule you have given.

Comment: That did it! The only addition I've had to make is to add limits and offsets to break it into smaller, completable chunks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible problem to solve - especially if you're not familiar with SQL.

In principle, I always treat this kind of data as "untrusted" - whatever rules you think apply usually turn out to be false over time.

My strategy is to use the "dirty" data to populate similar "clean" tables by running SQL queries, rather than try to work with the "dirty" data directly.

So, you might create two tables with the schema you think works best< and then populate that table by inserting `substring(columnB, 6)` into that table. By adding a where clause (e.g. `isnumeric(substring(t1.columnB, 6))`), you can validate your assumptions.

Once you have "clean" tables, you can perform the join easily.